# Can't send or receive mails with Mdaemon

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, mail-server

I have a Windows Server 2008 R2 with Mdaemon(v 10) installed. until today I have been unable to send or receive emails from/to any of provider such as yahoo, gmail, outlook, exchange...

I have tried creating a new account and create SMTP,pop3,pop,imap record in my DNS but nothing changed.

I don't have any Antivirus or firewall in my network.

how can I solve my problem?

Comment: If you try to send a test message out, are there any errors in the MDaemon-SMTP(out).log file? If you open the MDaemon-all.log file, do you see any errors? Are you able to Telnet to the MDaemon server from outside of your local network?

Comment: yah I check SMTP(out).log but nothing there!! empty page!!

Comment: I would like to have one of our support techs assist you with this issue. Please use the link below to open a ticket with our support staff. [http://www.altn.com/Support/RequestSupport/](http://www.altn.com/Support/RequestSupport/) Our support staff will be happy to work with you more closely to resolve this issue.